# Refresh a <div> in the HTML documents using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an `HTML` page with contents that I would like to refresh in every `30 seconds` using the `Ajax`.

```
<body id="page-top" class="index">
    <div id="main">
        <div>
            <h4>ADDRESS = <span id="wallet"></span></h4>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>BALANCE = <span id="balance"></span></h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script> 
        function getQueryString(name) { 
            var reg = new RegExp("(^|&)" + name + "=([^&]*)(&|$)", "i"); 
            var r = window.location.search.substr(1).match(reg); 
            if (r != null) 
                return unescape(r[2]); 
                return null; 
            }

            balance = getQueryString('balance'); 
            wallet = getQueryString('wallet');

            // document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML = Unit.fromSatoshis(balance).toBTC();
            // parseFloat(yourString).toFixed(2)
            document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML = parseFloat(balance/10e8).toFixed(4);
            document.getElementById('wallet').innerHTML = wallet.toLowerCase();
        </script>

        <!-- <script src="js/lib/unit.js"></script> -->
    </body>
```

The content is inside the `<div id="main">` and I need a script to refresh DOM element. How to do that using the `Ajax` ?

Comment: Java ?^^ don't misunderstand, it does have ANY relation with JS

Comment: Search Google... how to use ajax.

Comment: jQuery has a [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method that will replace the content of an element with the result of an HTTP request: this might be enough.

Comment: to refresh the div is to clear whatever is in it and use ajax to fetch a new data into it. This makes it look like it was refreshed.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service. Show us what you have tried

Comment: In the code you have provided, you haven't added a closing bracket to the `getQueryString` function. I'm also unsure if you are allowed to have two `return` statements in the same function in the same scope.

Comment: @SamBunting The first return statement is belong to the `if condition`. If the `if` is not satisfied, then the `second retrun` will come in action.

Comment: @Artin, Yes, but you have a second return statement immediately after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a div and assign an id.

```
<div id="my-div">
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
function loadDiv(){
    $('#my-div').load('yourlink.php',function () { //yourlink.php is the file which will be loaded in your div
         $(this).unwrap();
    });
}

loadDiv(); // This will run on page load

setInterval(function(){
    loadDiv() // this will run after every 30 seconds..
}, 30000);
```

Comment: I have a `JavaScript` project and there is no `PHP`

Comment: Please show your code in your question.

Comment: The page I work on is `balance.html`, can I write code like this 

`function autoRefresh_div() {
          $("#main").load("balance.html");
      };
      setInterval('autoRefresh_div()', 5000);` . 
I expect the code to refresh the `#main` in `every  5 secs`

Comment: Yes you can call your .html file, also you need to call your `autoRefresh_div();` once just before `setInterval` function.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the setTimeout() method of JavaScript.

Example:

```
function tasks() {
    // Your Ajax Code
}

setTimeout(tasks(), 30000) // Time in milliseconds
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

```js
/*
* method that call api and pass the response data to update the dom
*/
function setContents(){
  var configuration = {
  method:'GET',
  url:'/sampleUrl'}
  $.ajax(configuration).then(function(ajaxResponse){
    updateDom(ajaxResponse);

  });
}


/*
* data object has content and addresse
*/

function updateDom(data){
  var content = document.getElementById('content');
  content.innerHTML = data.content;
}

/*
* Call the method every 30 seconds
*/
setTimeOut(setContents, 30000);
```

Hope this helps!